# Google Geocode Map Response Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a Google Geocoding API Wrapper library (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-net/) to get/map a complete address but every now and then the response doesn't map correctly because Google didn't return all the address types and the indexes on the array do not reflect the correct location of the value I want or it throws a null exception.

CODE

```
    public AddressMapper(GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse)
    {
        AddressComponents = geocodeResponse.Results[0].AddressComponents;


        if (AddressComponents != null)
        {
            StreetNumber = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            Street = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            Neighborhood = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            City = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            Province = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            Country = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            Political = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            PostalCode = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            FormattedAddress = TryParse(AddressType.StreetNumber);
            //Latitude = address.Geometry.Location.Latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            //Longitude = address.Geometry.Location.Longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
>>> This seems to always be an empty string.
    private string TryParse(AddressType addressType)
    {
        if (AddressComponents == null) return "";
        foreach (var component in AddressComponents)
        {
            return component.Types.Contains(addressType) ? component.LongName : string.Empty;
        }
    return string.Empty;
}
}
```

RESPONSE (JSON)

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4219998,
               "lng" : -122.0839596
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4233487802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0826106197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4206508197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0853085802915
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How/What is the correct way of ensuring the element exists in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a guarantee for the returned types or the order of the `address_components`.

Iterate over all `address_components`, test if the `types` match a particular type and when it does set the related variable.

Comment: I tried             ` foreach (var component in AddressComponents)
            {
                return component.Types.Contains(addressType) ? component.LongName : string.Empty;
            } ` but every field is an empty string. addressType is an enum.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with c# , I can't tell you what's wrong with the loop.